# VB.NET Getting twitch viewers from webbrowser into a string

Tags: vb.net-2010

Okay so I'm using a web browser to navigate to a stream and I want to get the viewers amount into a label. I've searched around a lot on google and such but no luck. Some help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You need to be more specific about your question and post some more info.

Comment: @foibs I have tried using GetElementsByID and so on but it just says Object is no instance of blah blah –